# Is there a way on ubuntu to keep offline files like in windows?

Tags: windows, files, migration, offline

In windows there is a option when you browse network folders that copies selected files to local disk. Then you can work with those files, create, modify, delete and when you are in the same network as the origin pc those changes are synced.

I am talking about 5gb of files, so cloud services are out.

This is the scenario:
I choose files that i need for 2 weeks. I make then available offline. Then i go on a trip, during those two weeks i create new files, delete some files and modify some. I can't keep track manually of changes i made. Then i return home, log in on my laptop and the files are synced with the file server.
Then i repeat the process buy with different files this time.

Is there a way to have this feature in ubuntu ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should work with a control version application. Maybe Git. You can create your own server and client in the same computer, but normally is usefull to have it separated to guarantee that you don't lose nothing if the computer breaks.

To use and create a git server you can see [this instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Git).

But I sugest you to use [Bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org/) ou [github](http://github.com/) to do that job of creating the server. With them you won't have any headache by configuring the server. The first one has the advantage of having private data for free, the second only permits that by paying the service. By the way, I use bitbucket to all sort of things: for my rails projects, for my python applications, for my thesis (MS word, latex and images), and even for my design works that are images and blender videos.

Comment: Source control like git is not suited for this plus github and bitbucket are both online services. I have 35kb upload speed and 5gb of data to transfer in max 5-30 min so online services are out. For my development i use those services, but those projects are few MB max.

Comment: Yes, but you can create your own git server. The bitbucket and github were only alternatives to the first solution. ;)

Comment: Yes, but git is for storing source code mainly, not video and music files. It seems like a overkill ?

Comment: I know it's for source code, but if you want to have control of something and use history control to sync, the best choice is Git or some source control app.